# Custom performance summary functions in caret that use original data values

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using caret to train a classification model on a dataset, from which I take the outputted class probabilities and feed them into another set of calculations.  Specifically, I sum the class probabilities along one dimension of the original data and use that to calculate my eventual summary statistic describing the model quality of fit.

I currently have to train the model to maximize some other metric (I'm using Kappa right now), but what I really want to do is to write a summaryFunction to pass to trainControl that will encapsulate the entire calculation from start-to-finish.

The problem is that this summaryFunction would require the original data points, since I have to aggregate the class probabilities along a dimension of the original data in order to calculate the summary statistic.  The summaryFunction prototype doesn't seem to provide the data itself in any way that I can see.

Is there a simple solution here?  I suppose I could just make the original data frame global and use its values in my summaryFunction, provided that the class probabilities and predictions passed to the summaryFunction are in the same number and row order as the original data set?

Thank you very much!!